# VB.NET get path from the file the user opened

Tags: vb.net, media-player, filenames, filepath

I am developing a media player based on WMP.
If the user sets my media player as the default player to play .avi files for example, then clicks a random .avi file, my player will start successfully, however it will not load the file that the user opened.
So thats why I need a code that will get the path of the file the user opened, so that I can make the player load that file automatically after it has been started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` property. This gets you a list of commandline arguments. Launching a file from the explorer usually provides the path to the clicked file as the only argument, so use it like:

```
If My.Application.CommandLineArgs IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
   My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
    Dim UserFile As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
    PlayFile(UserFile)
End If
```

Comment: Sorry for being **a bit** late in voting but I completely forgot it and saw it today. Thanks it had worked great :)